# Is it possible to create Multifield using coral UI 3 in AEM 6.2?

Tags: aem

I have to create **Touch UI Dialogs** using **Coral UI 3**. Does Coral UI 3 supports **Multifield** (with different set of xtypes like Text field, Drop Downs etc..) in **AEM 6.2**??

Could anyone pls share any reference or example if you have??

Comment: Are you creating your own custom dialog widget? Or are you creating some AEM admin tool/ui? I have created a multifield with coral UI in my aem-selecto project: https://github.com/ahmed-musallam/aem-selecto/tree/master/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/selecto/components/content/main look at body.html and look at this js for the initialization https://github.com/ahmed-musallam/aem-selecto/blob/master/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/selecto/components/content/main/clientlibs/main/js/main.js. If thats what you are looking for, i can write up an appropriate answer.

Comment: Also, coral ui does not have “xtype” thats an extjs construct. Please clarify your question and add things you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a pretty thorough example on adobe help site.
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/htl_multifield62.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur support! Actually the link you have shared for Multi-field is using Coral 2. But i am expecting a solution for Coral 3 (Node structure for Dialog & sling:resourceType will be different for this compared with Coral 2.). Coral 3 reference - https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/legacy/coral2/migration.html

Comment: They also have a sample for 6.3 but not sure if it's coral 3. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/multifield_aem63.html